# is it possible to activate android gps via programming?

Tags: java, android, android-gps

I am developing an `APP` wanted to connect the GPS device, in fact, I do not want to prompt the user to manually activate would like to do automatically is it possible?

I know to ask the user to activate it manually now connect the `GPS` without request can not my app works with root access, if it has something that can be done with root it will also be valid

Answer (score 0):

The android platform relies upon permissions, you can most certainly use the GPS in your app, but the user will be notified at first use. After the user accepts your permission your app will be allowed to use GPS in background